# Friendly url pagination

Tags: .htaccess

I am new on that htaccess thing.

My problem is, I have a pagination on index.php:

```
http://localhost/index.php?pagina=2
```

I want to access this with this url:

```
http://localhost/page/2
```

I try on htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /page/(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1
```

but it gave me a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In per-directory .htaccess files the directory prefix, of where this .htaccess file is located, is removed from the URL-path when pattern matching. In the document root, this is simply `/` (a slash). So your `RewriteRule` would need to be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /index.php?pagina=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1
```

without first `/`